# How to compile node.js to binary release (with native modules)

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron, realm, bcrypt

Currently, I’m experimenting with building Node.js projects (different bundlers and other kinds of stuff). And I got a simple idea about bundling Node.js to a single binary for Linux, macOS, or Windows.

There are two packages `nexe` and `pkg` both of them don’t really support native `.node` modules that are used by packages like `bcrypt` or `realm`. Were you performing a similar compilation? I would be extremely happy to see some real-world examples (I could not find them on GitHub).

**But... for what?** It's more like an idea for fun what we're able to archive with Node.js. Even if it will be working (I get it working on `cjs` packages without native modules) example project with hello wold may have a size above 30MB.

One cool observation is that `@vercel/ncc` is able to compile my project into a single directory, but it also doesn’t work without `node_modules` (probably, I had no environment to test it)

**Update V1**: Building `realm` is impossible in such kinds of projects, the simplest solution is to not use `realm` in `node` apps because it will crash the binary build (it's because `realm` is using tons of other packages such as `electron` or `react-native` which doesn't work at all when it comes to desktop platforms.

My code is available at the following repository: https://github.com/keinsell/typecraft

Answer (score 3):

#### EDIT 2023

By the 2023, a new runtime was released which is called `bun` it seems to be able to compile projects into binary-like format, however problems with CJS/ESM compatibility are still the same and NAPI is not well supported either.

---

After days of struggling with researching how `pkg` works and searching for potential alternatives, I've found `caxa` which were working for me in a good way, and on the road, I also got `pkg` working fine with (actually only tested on `bcrypt`) native modules. My core insights on using `pkg` for building Node.js binaries are:

- Use matrix-builds on CI to build package ex. `win` package from `windows` host, `mac` from `macos` host etc.
- Be sure to include native modules to assets (there you can use `require()` function in JavaScript (example below) or use `pkg.assets` object in `package.json` - I don't really get it but it's contained in my issue on `vercel/pkg` - [vercel/pkg#1473](https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/1473)

```
+ require('bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node')

export async function main() { /* ... */ }
```

Some modules are still build-crashing, and the good example is `realm` but I'll still search for a way of building it and including it into node.js binary application. All of my progress on researching Node.js builds will be available on https://github.com/keinsell/typecraft and this StackOverflow answer will be updated over time and my new discoveries.

Answer (score 0):

Read this resource with examples and you will be able to compile it to a binary release. Of course, nexe is necessary but with pty.js you can successfully compile it with all the native libraries. Have a look at the source: https://www.jedi.be/blog/2013/05/14/compiling-packaging-a-nodejs-project-as-a-single-binary/

Comment: Sound good mate, I'll take a look

Comment: If it works for you. Please mark it as an answer mate :)

Comment: I have checked it and it's something like... if `pty` doesn't work use the pure-javascript equivalent of the package. This isn't about that so I can say this will not resolve the issue from my question. If I would like to do this in a similar way I would rather use `bcryptjs` than `bcrypt` and the problem would be solved but it's not about that.